# CUDA : error: "transfer of control bypasses initialization of" when creating thrust::device_ptr

Tags: c++, c, linux, cuda

I have this code line in my Cuda - C application :

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <time.h>

#include <device_functions.h>

int main()
{
    const int size = 32;
    unsigned int * dev_ips_range_end;
    unsigned int * ips_range_end = new unsigned int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ips_range_end[i] = i;



cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ips_range_end, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem !");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_ips_range_end, ips_range_end, size * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem !");
        goto Error;
    }

    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> dev_ips_range_end_ptr(dev_ips_range_end);
    thrust::inclusive_scan(dev_ips_range_end_ptr, dev_ips_range_end_ptr + size, dev_ips_range_end_ptr);
    return 0;

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_ips_range_end);
}
```

here is the command I used and the output:

[Test]$ nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib kernel.cu -o test.run
kernel.cu(27): error: transfer of control bypasses initialization of:
            variable "dev_ips_range_end_ptr"
(42): here

kernel.cu(32): error: transfer of control bypasses initialization of:
            variable "dev_ips_range_end_ptr"
(42): here

kernel.cu(39): error: transfer of control bypasses initialization of:
            variable "dev_ips_range_end_ptr"
(42): here

3 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000022ad_00000000-9_kernel.cpp1.ii".

the same code is working without any problem in visual studio on windows.
how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please provide a complete code that demonstrates the error, please also provide the exact and complete compile command line and the exact and complete error output from the compiler.  It should not be difficult if the only thing that is required is that one line of code (which happens to have a syntax error in it as you have it written.)  Which CUDA version are you using?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to provide code that wasn't provided by OP.  This is not correct editing procedure.

Comment: I have not done any cuda, but C++ global objects have their constructors called before main, something which is set up when making normal programs but if you are using global objects in a graphics card kernel you probably have to set it up manually.  That's what the error sounds like to me.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Kindly find the whole code :

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]  (<-- click here and read)  You can click "edit" to edit your own question to provide the MCVE.  Don't try to put it in the comments or in an external link.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have updated the question with the whole code, and the command I used to compile .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people might tell you that the use of `goto` in C/C++ isn't a great idea.  But to avoid arguments, and allow you to keep the same code structure, you can declare your thrust device pointer at the top of your program (before any `goto` statements) and then set the pointer value when you are ready to use it, like this:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <time.h>

#include <device_functions.h>

int main()
{
    const int size = 32;
    unsigned int * dev_ips_range_end;
    unsigned int * ips_range_end = new unsigned int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ips_range_end[i] = i;



    thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int> dev_ips_range_end_ptr;
cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ips_range_end, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem !");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_ips_range_end, ips_range_end, size * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem !");
        goto Error;
    }

    dev_ips_range_end_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev_ips_range_end);
    thrust::inclusive_scan(dev_ips_range_end_ptr, dev_ips_range_end_ptr + size, dev_ips_range_end_ptr);
    return 0;

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_ips_range_end);
}
```

Comment: Note that your use of `goto Error` in all 3 cases will actually theoretically allow an invalid usage of `cudaFree`.  After your first `goto` statement, `dev_ips_range_end` has not been properly allocated by `cudaMalloc`, so passing it to `cudaFree` at that point would technically throw an error (although you are not checking for errors there.)  Likewise if the `cudaMalloc` call fails, the subsequent `goto` statement would also incorrectly cause a `cudaFree` attempt on `dev_ips_range_end`, which would also throw an error.  It's a nit, really.